# Finding elementary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So let's consider these matrices $$A=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\2 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}$$
$$
    B =\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2\\
    -1 & 1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

And the question is to find the invertible matrix $X$ such that $AX=B$ and express $X$ as a product of **2** elementary matrices.

What I know I tried:
So I do know that you could easily get X by inverting A and multiplying it by B but I need the two elementary matrices so i tried a different solution.

$$(A\cdot E_{1})\cdot E_{2} = B$$

So what I did was to try to make A equal to by elementary row operations and doing the same to another 2 $\times$ 2 identity matrix.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\2 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

$$R_{1} \iff R_{2}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1\\-1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

$$R_{1} + R_{2} \implies R_{1} $$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 0\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\-1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

So I was able to arrive to C in two elementary operations like the problem specified. But then when I try to check with my original equation:

$$(A\cdot E_{1})\cdot E_{2} = B   $$
$$\begin{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\2 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\\\end{bmatrix}\end{pmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1& 1\\1 & 0\\\end{bmatrix}$$

It doesn't equal to C. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong? I have tried to do the calculation over and over and I still arrive at the same thing. Where is my mistake here? Is it the process itself?

Comment: Is there a typo in your first declaration of $A$? In the first instance its top-left coefficient is $1$, but in all later instances the top-left coefficient is $-1$.

Comment: Yeah it was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You're doing *row* operations, but the equation $AX=B$ indicates that you must multiply on the *right*, which means you should be doing *column* operations instead.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, I agree, but the OP is doing row operations literally to turn $A$ into $B$, which means we're writing $(E_1E_2)A = B$, not what we want. I admit I'm not studying what the OP wrote too carefully, but I do know linear algebra pretty well.

Comment: @TedShifrin So what exactly what i'm doing wrong? Is my understanding of the problem wrong?

Comment: Yes. As I tried to explain, when you do row operations, you're multiplying $A$ on the *left* by elementary matrices. So to get $A\cdot (E_1E_2)$, with the multiplication on the right, you must do *column* operations instead. As Jean-Claude points out, there are of course other ways of doing the problem, which amount to solving $Ax=b$ by reducing an augmented matrix to reduced echelon form.

Comment: @TedShifrin You are right. I misinterpreted what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @TedShifrin If I try to do by reducing an augmented matrix to its RREF form, what would the augmented matrix be? Also, by column operations, do you mean i should transpose(Ax=B)?

Comment: Yes, transposing and doing row operations would work. You augment and do $[A|B]$ the way you solve linear systems. When you get $[I|X]$, this tells you $X$, but doesn't give $X$ as a product of elementary matrices in any obvious way.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah wait. So i would have A = AI and not A = IA? I think thats what I got wrong? So then I here when I reduced A to its RREF, would be the inverse of A which is what the question is asking for?

Comment: You're now ignoring $B$, so I do not follow. Ultimately, as someone responded, $X=A^{-1}B$, independent of the elementary matrices.

Comment: @TedShifrin I get that part. But getting the elementary matrices is what i'm confused about. Could you walk me through the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to calculate $A^{-1}B$ and you'll see that the matrix is different from $E_1E_2$ , so because of the inverse of a square matrix is unique (and so $A^{-1}B$ too) your method is wrong.

---

To solve the problem I would use a property of the traspose matrix, namely :

$$(KA)^T=A^TK^T$$

To use this find the elementary matrices for the system :
$$KA^T = B^T$$
with $K=E_2E_1$,
and then traspose everything , obtaining :

$$(E_2E_1A^T)^T = (B^T)^T \iff AE_1^TE_2^T = B$$

Comment: Thats what I found too when I do A^−1B. But the question is specifically asking for expressing it into two elementary matrices.

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible way! @Duts

Comment: There's a problem though :D, it seems to me that you need 4 elementary operations to solve  $K A^T = B^T$. Have you been able to find just **2** matrices?

Comment: That's actually my biggest confusion. I already know how to solve everything. But i'm not sure about just using TWO elementary matrices. But I was able to find two.  What I did is to augment a 2 x 2 identity matrix beside the M that I found using the determinant. So I tried to reduce the 2 x 2 matrix into its RREF form which will require more than 2 steps. But after my first step, the resulting M matrix is also actually an elementary matrix. I just used that and then the corresponding identity matrix in my first step which gives me the two elementary matrix.Checking everything, it checks out.

Comment: Its so weird tho. Took me sooo long to figure out what's happening. The question is just really weird overall, why can't they just ask for all the elementary matrices.